# Alert Field is off by one

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a sample Map application where the user can drop pins and label them with appropriate descriptions.  It's close to working, but the descriptions are off by one.  That is, the first pin I drop will have the default text, and the second pin will have the description I entered for the first, and so on.

I've struggled with this code and I realize there are other problems.  Once I get it working I'll put it on Code Review but feel free to point out any other errors.

I've highlighted the relevant method but included everything in the ViewController.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var location: CLLocation!
    var newAnnotation: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    @IBAction func refreshMap(sender: AnyObject) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        location = locationManager.location
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() //not my question right now but I'm pretty sure this is dumb
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        refreshMap(self.map)
        let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addPlace:")
        uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1
        map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)
    }

    //this is the method in question
    func addPlace(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.map)
            let newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = map.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.map)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Memorable Place", message: "Enter a description for this location", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
                textField.text = "Description"
            })

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                self.newAnnotation = alert.textFields![0].text
            }))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            annotation.title = newAnnotation
            map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the last two lines of the AddPlace method (where you add the annotation to the map) into the alert's action handler. The action handler is called asynchronously, at some time in the future.